# tsql : Delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DELETE abc 
FROM abc INNER JOIN xyz ON 
abc.RECORD_TYPE = xyz.RECORD_TYPE AND 
abc.IN = xyz.IN 
OPTION (MERGE JOIN, LOOP JOIN)
```

can anyone tell me what exactly the query doing ?

Comment: It's good to show you've made a bit of effort. Can you tell us what you think it's doing? Or what you want it to do?

Comment: If you change the delete abc to select abc.* it will return the records the statement would delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `DELETE` all the records from the table `abc` with `JOIN` to another table. It deletes all the records in the table `abc` that has a `RECORD_TYPE` value equal to the `RECORD_TYPE` in the other table AND in the same time the value `IN` are equals in the two table.

It is a normal [**`DELETE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) clause, Where the `FROM` can contain extra joined table as specified by the documentation:

> FROM clause:
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can be used instead of a subquery
> in the WHERE clause to identify rows to be removed.

Comment: @sheena : i am new to SQL and my TL gave this one for analysis.